# C# pdf generator with flexible options

Tags: c#, asp.net

I want create a online page designer … a system that user can design her own page and can insert title , table , picture and ... and set location of elements in page and set size for page (like A4) and more and save it to system ... and anytime can download it as pdf … my framework is dotnet blazor server side … is there any library can help me for that or I must make it from scratch ?

I founded pdfsharp or stimulsoft … but I want that user operate design not developers

what is best and free pdf generator that very flexible ?

i want design page by user in javascript Json object and from json, generate pdf in backend system

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can Use Syncfusion’s Essential PDF (.NET PDF library).

https://www.syncfusion.com/document-processing/pdf-framework/net

The whole suite of controls is available for free (commercial applications also) through the community license program if you qualify. The community license is the full product with no limitations or watermarks.

Note: I work for Syncfusion.